# Save complex objects and their sons entities ORM Lite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, ormlite, foreign-collection

I'm using ORM Lite on a project , I decided to use the facility to make the persistence part of the Web service once and can reuse it on Android.

But I am suffering a lot because possou complex objects that have multiple ForeignCollectionField and Foreign object , and at the hour of perssistir temenda these data is a headache, because I have to enter one by one of their children , I think the idea of ​​an ORM is make life easier , ie you have to persist the object and father and all the rest is done behind the scenes ...

Well, it is now too late to give up lite ORM , I wonder if there is a way to do what sitei above ..

I found a piece of code [here](http://pastebin.com/2YdPfdkX)

tried to implement but it seems not work , just keeps saving the parent object .

follows the function I'm trying to use , but do not know whether imports are correct because the code I found in the link above did not have this data

```
public int create(Object entity, Context context) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException, SQLException {
    try{
        if (entity!=null){
            // Class type of entity used for reflection
            Class clazz = entity.getClass();

            // Search declared fields and save child entities before saving parent.
            for(Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                // Inspect annotations
                Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
                try{
                    for(Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                        // Only consider fields with the DatabaseField annotation
                        if(annotation instanceof DatabaseField) {
                            // Check for foreign attribute
                            DatabaseField databaseField = (DatabaseField)annotation;
                            if(databaseField.foreign()) {
                                // Check for instance of Entity
                                Object object = field.get(entity);

                                Dao gDao = getDatabase(context).getDao(object.getClass());
                                gDao.create(object);
                            }
                        }else if (annotation instanceof ForeignCollectionField){
                            Object object = field.get(entity);
                            for(Object obj : new ArrayList<Object>((Collection<?>)object)){
                                Class c = obj.getClass();

                                Dao gDao = getDatabase(context).getDao(obj.getClass());
                                gDao.create(obj);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }catch (NullPointerException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // Retrieve the common DAO for the entity class
            Dao dao =  getDatabase(context).getDao(entity.getClass());

            // Persist the entity to the database
            return dao.create(entity);
        }else
            return 0;
    }finally {
        if (database != null) {
            OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();
            database = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Leveraging the same post, also need a colução to delete cascade, imagine a situation where I have the following tables:

Company > Category> person> contact> Phone and email

Deleting and now I do as described in the documentation:

```
public int deleteCascade(Prefeitura prefeitura, Context context){
        try{
            Dao<Prefeitura, Integer> dao = getDatabase(context).getDao(Prefeitura.class);
            DeleteBuilder db = dao.deleteBuilder();
            db.where().eq("prefeitura_id", prefeitura.getId());
            dao.delete(db.prepare());
            // then call the super to delete the city
            return dao.delete(prefeitura);


        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

But the objects that are not directly linked the company would still be in the database, how could I do?

But without hacks, I want a clean code ...

I know ORM Lite really is lite, but one that saves the children create and delete cascade is essential for any ORM, hopefully for the next versions it is implemented, it is regrettable not have these features, for simple projects is very good, but in a complex project because a lot of headaches, I'm feeling on the skin.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Sorry but I don't have the cycles right now to properly address this.  Maybe post it on the android mailing list?  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ormlite-android

Comment: Ok, it's already posted, but do you have any idea how to solve the problem of delete? A clear sense of the parent object and its children form ...